# the constructor 'DisableAttribute(Type)' is not supported. Error generating functions metadata for service bus queue triggered Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have tried to disable function app in runtime by updating the app settings value. By using the overload of disable attribute. But have been getting error for the below code

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DisableFunctionApp
{
    public static class Function5
    {
        [Disable(typeof(DoWorkDisableProvider))]
        [FunctionName("Function5")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("cds-storage-queue", Connection = "dv-svcbus-events_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_TIMER_DISABLED5", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process));
            log.LogInformation($"function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MY_TIMER_DISABLED5", "1");           
        }
    }

    public class DoWorkDisableProvider
    {
        public bool IsDisabled(this MethodInfo method)
        {
            // check if the function should be disable
            // return true or false
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_TIMER_DISABLED5", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Error       the constructor 'DisableAttribute(Type)' is not supported.
Error generating functions metadata

microsoft.net.sdk.functions: v3.0.7

Any help in solving the issue

Comment: Hi, any update on this question?

Answer (score -2):

Your code should be like this:

```
    [Disable("MY_TIMER_DISABLED")]
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        return new OkObjectResult("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
```

And the step of change the settings should be at the starting of your function app.

You can give the setting 'MY_TIMER_DISABLED' a default value. For example, this is my settings:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "MY_TIMER_DISABLED": "true"
  }
}
```

So with the above settings, the function will be disabled by default. Please let me know whether you can solve it:)

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about using the attribute with the overload that takes a Type argument.